# Related to "vagueness" definition

Tags: philosophy-of-science, terminology

We got quiz today in the classroom. One of the questions are given below. I would be happy to hear your feedback on my answers.

> Which ones are true for "vague" definition?
>
> 1. It means that it is at least possible that there are things for which it is indeterminate whether the term applies to them or not.
> 2. It means that people have conflicting ideas about what the exact meaning of the term is.
> 3. It means that it refers to different things depending on contextual factors, such as time and place.
> 4. It means that there is no sharp limit between the things the term does apply to and the things it does not apply to.
> 5. It means that it is meaningless.

---

To me,
1: False,
2: True,
3: True,
4: True,
5: False.

Am I right?

---

Sometimes, it is easy to mix "vague" with "ambiguity"...

Comment: 4. is "the True one" : it is the def of [Vagueness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I agree with 4. However, is it only 4 true? I tend to now think that 2 is false, but probably 3 is (weakly) true!?